# Does ImageMagick's resize command (mogrify) require any DLLs?

Tags: dll, imagemagick, static-libraries, imagemagick-convert

I [downloaded](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows) the no-installer version of ImageMagick ([ImageMagick-6.8.6-8-Q16-x86-windows.zip](http://www.imagemagick.org/download/binaries/ImageMagick-6.8.6-8-Q16-x86-windows.zip)) to use in a project, but it's quite big at 123MB.

I only need `mogrify.exe` to do a simple image resize. I copied it to a separate directory, and it runs fine, but I'm not sure whether I already have some of the required DLLs (the user may not have these).

I ran [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) on `mogrify`, but it said there were no DLLs in use by the image.

Is this correct or do I also need to include any of these?

```
atl100.dll mfc100.dll msvcp100.dll msvcr100.dll vcomp100.dll X11.dll Xext.dll
```

(full list from the zip file)

I believe `vcomp100.dll` is part of the Visual C++ redistributable, so I guess I should include this, in case that isn't installed on the user's machine?

On the flip-side, `X11.dll` [looks unnecessary](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/INSTALL-windows.html#windows-xp-vista-7-visual-c-6-0-through-9-0-compilation).

Is there an easier way to figure this out, other than researching each individual DLL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `vcomp100.dll` library is the only dependency for resizing within `mogrify.exe`. For safety, you should re-distribute that DLL in the same directory as the executable.

> Is there an easier way to figure this out, other than researching each individual DLL?

I can't answer what the easiest method would be (outside of reading each libraries documentation), but I would highly suggest authoring a [unit test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing)
to ensure all the expect functionality of your requirements are meet. I was able to run a test suite on a vanilla install of XP (via [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/)), and confirmed that resizing of PNG, JPEG, and basic [drawing](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/draw/) work without additional dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

To discover executables and dll dependencies on Windows you can use [DependencyWalker](http://www.dependencywalker.com) (free tool). ProcessExplorer only tells you which DLLs are loaded by a process in the a specific moment you examine it. A DLL may be loaded on demand or not at all, depending on the needs of the executable, thus DependencyWalker can help you in more cases.

Comment: DependencyWalker shows 8 ImageMagic DLLs for mogrify.exe. If I copy all this 8 DLLs to the same path, it still doesn't work because of a missing ´IM_MOD_RL_jpeg_.dll´. A copy of this DLL in the same path as the other 8 doesn't help. What can I do?

Comment: It works with the portable version ´ImageMagick-6.9.0-0-Q16-x86-windows.zip´. This includes the portable Win32 static at 16 bits-per-pixel version. Just copy to your host and run (no installer, no Windows registry entries). You just need 1 single ´mogrify.exe´